# How to change "unable to locate element" to another message like "Element doesn't exist" in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using Selenium Webdriver and I want to print some messages after each step so I am able to print some message upon success but on failures I receive "unable to locate element". Please see my code:

```
   WebElement a= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eviceSliderbuttonPrev']/a"));

   if(a.isDisplayed())
   {
       System.out.println("Device Slider button exists");

       a.click();

       System.out.println("Button is clickable");
   }
  else {
       System.out.println("Device Slider button doesn't exist!");
```

but the else condition is not printed out when the case is failing and I get "unable to locate element".

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `findElement` either returns element or throws `NoSuchElementException`, so `if(a.isDisplayed())` condition would be meet only if element found.

If you want to check existence of the element, I would suggest try using `findElements` instead and check the size of the list because `findElements` always returns either empty list or list of `WebElement`.

You should try as below :-

```
List<WebElement> a= driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eviceSliderbuttonPrev']/a"));

if(a.size() > 0 && a.get(0).isDisplayed())
{
   System.out.println("Device Slider button exists");
   a.get(0).click();
   System.out.println("Button is clickable");
 }else {
   System.out.println("Device Slider button doesn't exist!");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! this answered my questions .. I am a beginner and the list <webelement> is what is missing for me ...
thank you lots!

Comment: @Zomzomzom no problem. Glad to help you.. happy learning...:)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of isDisplayed() which throws a NoSuchElementException instead of returning false, when the element is not displayed, you can use driver.findElements(...) which will return a list. Just check the size of the list to be 0 or 1 instead of handling exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch :

```
try {
   if(a.isDisplayed()) {
       System.out.println("Device Slider button exists");
       a.click();
   }
 } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Device Slider button doesn't exist!");
 }
```

You could take the if condition out of the above if you wanted, but that's up to you. The exception is still thrown in the console however you're controlling it in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this answer is an alternative approach to using driver.findElements() method.
As Moser suggested in his answer, you can use try-catch. 
However, the driver.findElement() method will throw NoSuchElementException if that element was not present or was not located and program will terminate there itself without reaching the 'try' block.

So, we would have to put driver.findElement() method itself inside the 'try' block.

```
try {
    WebElement a= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='eviceSliderbuttonPrev']/a"));
    // If above line throws NoSuchElementException, rest of the try block below will be skipped and you can print your desired message.
    if (a != null) { // Element was present and found.
        if(a.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("Device Slider button exists");
            a.click();
            System.out.println("Button is clickable");
        }
    }
}
catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException) {
    System.out.println("Device Slider button doesn't exist!");
}
```